# Continuous Approximation Lemma proof

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, approximation

Real Analysis student wanting a hint to the following problem:

Let E be a measurable set with m(E) < ∞, and let $\chi_{\small{E}}$ be its characteristic
function.

Prove that for any  $\epsilon$> 0, there is a step function
h(x) such that $m(\{h \neq\chi_{\small{E}}\}) < \epsilon$.
Hint: Use the existence of an open set O containing E for which
$m(O ∼ E) < \epsilon$.)

I'm struggling to see how to start given the following information...

Thanks!

Comment: I think the defintion of a step function is that the function can take only finitely many values, each on some set *which need not be an interval*(this is important, I think for Lebesgue integration this is not necessary). If this is the case, you can just take a step function which is one on $O$ and $0$ outside $O$, where $m(O \sim E) < \epsilon$. Then, of course the condition is obvious.

Comment: If a step function were a function that takes finitely many values on sets that need not be intervals, you could just define $h$ as the characteristic function itself. From some googling, it seems like it has to be intervals. User5634, I think this might help - show that any open set $O$ in $\mathbb{R}$ is a countable union of disjoint open intervals and use that.